# How to properly darken and show text on mouseover in a box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make image gallery using css and jquery. I am having the following problems:-

1. when I hover over the box h4 and p of all the boxes appears along with the box on which I hover. I want text to appear on those boxes only on which I hover.
2. I am going to use background images in boxes instead of boxes. My code is not working whenever I hover on the box background - image does not darken.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".grid").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("darkbackground");
  $(".grid h4,.grid p").css("display","block");
 });

 $(".grid").mouseout(function(){
  $(".grid h4,.grid p").css("display","none");
  $(this).removeClass("darkbackground");
 });

});
```

```css
.image-grids{
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
}

.image-grids-row{
 display: table-row;
 width: 100%;
}


.grid{
 width: 25%;  /**********In responsive design make it 50%;**********/
 height: 300px;
 display: table-cell;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.grid h4,.grid p{
 display: none;
 padding: 10px;
}

.darkbackground{
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image-grids">
        <div class="image-grids-row">
            
            <div class="grid" style="background:red;">
                <h4>Ibiza</h4>
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid" style="background:yellow;">
                <h4>New Zealand</h4>
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid" style="background:green;">
                <h4>Goa</h4>
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid" style="background:pink;">
                <h4>Maldives</h4>
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to target the hovered element. Then you can use `find()` to get the element you want.

**Background-color:**  The background color property did not get applied beacuse it was ovewritten by the inline style you are giving.

You can use `!important` in your CSS, but you could better use id's at each `.grid` element in order to apply background colors from the CSS (not inline)

For example:

Instead of:

```
<div class="grid" style="background:red;">
```

you can use:

```
<div id="grid_red" class="grid">
```

and in CSS:

```
#grid_red { background-color:red }
```

**Background-image:**  The idea is to put a div with class `.image-cover` inside each `.grid` div and give them a `position:absolute`. Also, give a `position:relative` to each `.grid` element. Then, on .grid:hover, apply a background color of `rgba(0,0,0,0.3)`. Check the first div and continue on your own

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".grid").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("darkbackground");
  $(this).find("h4").css("display","block");
        $(this).find("p").css("display","block");
 });

 $(".grid").mouseout(function(){
  $(".grid h4,.grid p").css("display","none");
  $(this).removeClass("darkbackground");
 });

});
```

```css
.image-grids{
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
}

.image-grids-row{
 display: table-row;
 width: 100%;
}

.image-cover {  
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.darkbackground .image-cover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3)!important;
}

#grid-one {
    background-image: url('http://www.techinsights.com/uploadedImages/Public_Website/Content_-_Primary/Teardowncom/Sample_Reports/sample-icon.png');
}

.grid{
 width: 25%;  /**********In responsive design make it 50%;**********/
 height: 300px;
 display: table-cell;
 border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
.grid h4,.grid p{
 display: none;
 padding: 10px;
}

.darkbackground{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)!important;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image-grids">
        <div class="image-grids-row">
            
            <div id="grid-one" class="grid">
                <h4>Ibiza</h4>
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
                 <div class="image-cover"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid" style="background:yellow;">
                <h4>New Zealand</h4>
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid" style="background:green;">
                <h4>Goa</h4>
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>

            <div class="grid" style="background:pink;">
                <h4>Maldives</h4>
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, please also look at my second problem i.e. background does not darken on mouseover!

Comment: Thanks I just have one more problem! The image on hover is completely replacing the background. I want to darken the background image that is the background image should become more dark and opacity should decrease